# Power BI(DAX)- Create measure to count distinct rows filtered by condition

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have below `Customer Transactions` data. In a month, customer may buy one or multiple times data pack ,or may not buy data pack.

Irrespective of how many times data purchased in a month by a customer. I'm trying to find number of months that each customer purchased the data.
[image]

`Total Subscribed Months` is expected column.

Since customer may buy `Data Subscribed (GB)` more than once in a month. First I'm calculating `Total Data Purchased` in a month by customer.

```
Total Data Purchased = CALCULATE(
                    SUM('Customer Transactions'[Data Subscribed (GB)]),
                        ALLEXCEPT('Customer Transactions','Customer Transactions'[Account Number],'Customer Transactions'[Date])
    )
```

Second, Calculate number of months customer purchased the data pack.

```
Total Subscribed Months = 
CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT('Customer Transactions'[Account Number] ),
            'Customer Transactions'[Total Data Purchased]>0
            )
```

But its not working. Please advise how to correct formulae ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your table looks like this:

| Account Number | CUSTOMER_TYPE | Data Subscribed(GB) | Free Data | Date | Total Subscribed Months |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | Retail | 250 | 0 | 01 October 2019 | 1 |
| 10001 | Retail | 0 | 100 | 01 November 2019 | 1 |
| 10002 | Retail | 200 | 0 | 01 October 2019 | 1 |
| 10002 | Retail | 250 | 0 | 01 November 2019 | 2 |
| 10003 | Retail | 300 | 0 | 01 October 2019 | 2 |
| 10003 | Retail | 0 | 0 | 01 October 2019 | 2 |
| 10003 | Retail | 100 | 0 | 01 October 2019 | 2 |
| 10003 | Retail | 100 | 0 | 01 November 2019 | 2 |
| 10003 | Retail | 100 | 0 | 01 November 2019 | 2 |
| 10003 | Retail | 0 | 0 | 01 December 2019 | 2 |

## DAX Calculations

### Total Subscribed Months

```
Total Subscribed Months = 
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Customer Transactions'[Date] ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( 'Customer Transactions'[Data Subscribed(GB)] ), [Data Subscribed(GB)] > 0 )
)
```

### Total Data Purchased

```
Total Data Purchased = 
    SUM('Customer Transactions'[Data Subscribed(GB)])
```

## Output

Table visual with `Account Number`, `Total Subscribed Months` and `Total Data Purchased`.

[image]